# Cannot pass string to method after indexOf

Tags: java

I am almost finished with a program that takes user input and encrypts the message then displays it back. For some reason I am unable to pass the string to my encryption method and return it. Does anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Thank you so much to anyone who responds!

```
public static String doEncryption(String s)
{
    char alphabet[]  = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
        'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
        'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    char key[] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
        'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
        'x', 'y', 'z', 'a' };

    char encoded[] = new char[(s.length())];
    String encrypted="";
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        //System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        boolean isFound = false;
        j = 0;
        while (j < alphabet.length && !isFound){


            if (alphabet[j]==s.charAt(i)){
               encrypted=encrypted+key[j];
               isFound=true;
            }
            j++; 
        }

        if(j>=alphabet.length){
            encrypted=encrypted+s.charAt(i);
        }
       }        
    return (new String(encrypted));
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
    String match = "QUIT";
    String en = "";
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Encoding Program!");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the text you want encoded below.  Type QUIT when finished. ");
    en = sc.nextLine();
    String trim = en.substring(0, en.indexOf("QUIT"));
    doEncryption(trim.toLowerCase());
    //String en = doEncryption(sc.nextLine().toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("The text is encoded as: " + trim.toUpperCase());
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: `For some reason` ? what are those

Comment: What do you mean by you can't? do you get an error? does nothing happen? Be more specific please

Comment: You have to assign the result to some other variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your method *returns* the updated string, so you'll want to use that return value when calling it. Change:

```
doEncryption(trim.toLowerCase());
```

to

```
String updatedValue = doEncryption(trim.toLowerCase());
```

or reuse `trim` if you like:

```
trim = doEncryption(trim.toLowerCase());
```

...and then use `updatedValue` or `trim` to show the result.

Comment: Ah that did it thanks! Now that its all working, I am running test cases and my first one presents an error! If I type in say "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" where I would expect encrpytion to create "BCDEFGH....." I get an error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
 at cipher2.main(cipher2.java:46)
What is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: @still2blue See my answer, I prevent you about this. It happen because you have entered a string which does not contains "QUIT" so index-of return -1 which is not a valid bound for `substring`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you never re-assign the value.

Change

```
doEncryption(trim.toLowerCase());
```

to

```
trim = doEncryption(trim.toLowerCase());
```

then `System.out.println("The text is encoded as: " + trim.toUpperCase());` will display the correct value.

Beware of this line

```
en.substring(0, en.indexOf("QUIT"));
```

It will throw a [`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) if "QUIT" is not in the string.

I think you want the program to execute until "QUIT" is entered so you need to loop over until the input is "QUIT". Your main method would look like this

```
String match = "QUIT";
String en = "";
System.out.println("Welcome to the Encoding Program!");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the text you want encoded below.  Type QUIT when finished. ");
do
{
    en = sc.nextLine();

    if(!en.toUpperCase().equals(match))
    {
        en = doEncryption(en.toLowerCase());

        System.out.println("The text is encoded as: " + en.toUpperCase());
    }
} while(!match.equals(en.toUpperCase()));
sc.close();
```

When you want to exit, simply input quit.

Comment: So then what do I use to remove QUIT? I made the change you suggested but still get the error because of the substring line..

Comment: I figured it out, I was forgetting QUIT, now though if I type "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZQUIT" it doesn't recognize QUIT and encrypts it, how do I change that?

Comment: validate for `if(string.contains("QUIT"))`

Comment: It's all working fine except for one thing: Welcome to the Encoding Program!
Enter the text you want encoded below.  Type QUIT when finished. 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ quit QUIT
The text is encoded as: BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAZ RVJU 
why is it adding an extra Z at the end of the encrypted message?

Comment: Got it! It was a condition in my loop, had <= instead of <. That fixes the Z but then if I use that, no spaces are included in my output! Any ideas?